# Application of Cauchy Theorem on boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

If a complex function is analytical inside of a boundary, but has a singular point on the boundary itself, does the Cauchy Theorem still apply?  In other words, is the integral over the closed boundary still equal to zero?

Comment: That integral might not converge.

Answer (score 0):

No, because, in that case, there is no reason to suppose that the integral makes sense. Remember: when we integrate along a path, all the points of the path must belong to the domain of the function.

Comment: \begin{align*}
 \oint_C \frac{z}{z^2 + 4z + 3} \ dz &= \oint_C \frac{\frac{3}{2}}{z+3} \ dz - \oint_C \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{z+1} \ dz \quad    \text{where C:} \left|z+1\right| = 2\\
&= 0 - \pi i\\
&= -\pi i
\end{align*} Here I wrongly used the Cauchy Integral Theorem.  But if I use the Cauchy Integral Formula, I can rewrite this integral as \begin{equation*} \oint_C \frac{\frac{1}{z+3}}{z+1} dz = -\pi \end{equation*}. I guess this was just happenstance!  Just wanted to show why I was confused about it.  Thanks for the swift response.